# Multiple asynchronous Ajax calls inside each loop in Jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery, asynchronous

I want to call multiple APIs inside a loop (ex: $.each). I can do this with `async:false` mode but it makes the script lag. How to achieve this in synchronized mode? Just ignoring `async` option makes only the last element in `list` to be sent to api calls.

```
$.each(lists, function(index, value) {

            channel = lists[index].channel;
            list = lists[index].list;

            $.ajax({
                url : 'api.php?list=' + list + '&from=' + from + '&to=' + to,
                dataType : 'json',
                async : false,
                success : function(data) {
                    obj = data;

                    $.ajax({
                        url : 'api.php?list=' + list + '&from=' + from + '&to=' + to + '&action=sender',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        async : false,
                        success : function(data) {

                            obj['senders'] = data.msg;
                            CommonContainer.inlineClient.publish(channel, obj);

                        }
                    });

                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250746/process-chain-of-functions-without-ui-block/13252018#13252018

Comment: what do you mean makes only the last one sent to api calls? looking at _.after may be useful, you can create a function that will run after it has been called X amount of times. I use it if I am making, say, 5 AJAX calls and want something to run if they all succeed. - if you want an example let me know and i can throw one together

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate. The problem here was a declaration bug making the closure unable to protect the variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `channel` and `list` are global (or declared out of the scope of the function passed to `$.each`) and thus aren't protected by the closure.

Use this :

```
  var channel = lists[index].channel;
  var list = lists[index].list;
```

You should also declare `obj` as

```
  var obj = ...
```