# Chaining a series of ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a series of ajax calls that need to run sequentially, but not synchronously. What's the best way to do this?

I know I can you `$.when().then()`, but that only works for two ajax calls, no? Ideally, I'd love to do something like:

```
var caller;
for (var i = 0; i < argObjects.length; i++) {
    if (typeof caller === 'undefined') {
        caller = $.when($.ajax(... data: argObjects[i]...));
    }
    else {
        caller.then($.ajax(... data: argObjects[i]...));
    }
}
```

In other words, just tack on a series on `then`'s to chain 'em all together. But this isn't possible. Is there another way to do it with jQuery?

It's important to note that these calls CANNOT run at the same time. I could run a loop over them as set `async: false`, but that takes control away from the user while it processes which isn't good.

An alternative way of thinking about it would be to send everything in one call... but then how do I monitor the progress of that task as it runs? Say I have 10 weeks of data to update and I want to be notified as each week completes. If I sent 10 sequential ajax calls, each one could return and tell me that it has completed and I could update a progress bar of some sort. That's really the ultimate goal here.

I'll keep trying to wrap my head around deferreds in jQuery in the meantime.

Comment: Do you want to continue running the rest of the requests if one in the middle fails?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250746/process-chain-of-functions-without-ui-block/13252018#13252018

Comment: @Dogbert: No, I would rather not. Chaining the calls in `success` would seem to prevent it.

Comment: @slebetman - Thanks. Your solution is similar to jfriend00's if a little bit fancier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a different approach using a success handler to launch the next ajax call and just use a counter to keep track of which request you're running:

```
var i = 0;
function run() {
    $.ajax(... data: argObjects[i]..., function() {
        i++;
        if (i < argObjects.length) {
            run();
        }
    });
}
run();
```

Comment: Ahh, bloody recursion. Why didn't I think of that? Let me whip something up and see if it does the trick.

Comment: @Depressio - it isn't actually technically recursion (though it kind of looks like it).  The first call of `run()` is actually complete before the success handler is called and thus before the next execution of `run()` starts.

Comment: True. Callbacks are a bit different. It sure looks similar though. Anyway, I gave it a shot and it worked just fine. I guess I was trying to be too fancy using deferred chaining. :)

Answer (score 1):

For sequential ajax calls what i have is calling another ajax inside the success of first ajax.

Like this:-

```
function ajax1(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "",
    data: dataString,
    type: "POST" ,
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,   
    success: function(response_data){
        ajax2(); // call second ajax on success
    }
  });
}

function ajax2(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "",
    data: dataString,
    type: "POST" ,
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,   
    success: function(response_data){

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You can easily generalize this by storing the functions in an array. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250746/process-chain-of-functions-without-ui-block/13252018#13252018 for something similar.