# Array of JSON Objects is Undefined When Passed to a Function

Tags: javascript, arrays

first function gets json from a url and pushes it into array

```
var resultsArr = new Array();

// getResults()
// JSON response function -> takes uuid returned from search query
// and pings reponse url for any/all JSON objects of returned data
function getResults(req_uuid) {
    console.log("url fetched");
    $.getJSON( $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/respond?id=" + req_uuid, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        resultsArr.push(data);
    });
}
```

I have another function that runs on a click of a button that will pass `uuid` into `getResults()` at a given interval. This is all working. I'm even converting the entire array to a string and appending it into a div just before the call to the function in question. (this is also working). I'm logging the number of elements in the array before the call;

`console.log( resultsArr.length + " items in array")`

this logs = `4 items in array`

then the function is called;

```
function showResults(array) {
    var index = array.length;
    console.log( index + " items in array");

}
```

this returns `undefined items in array`. I am severely baffled.

Comment: What's the scope of your `resultsArr`? Make sure it is scoped globally, i.e. not defined within a function, if you are going to make such global references to it.

Comment: how is `showResults` called?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460556/undefined-return-value-from-the-function-call-javascritpt/17460802#17460802

Comment: As for how to do this in a loop (from you comment on an answer) see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631774/coordinating-parallel-execution-in-node-js/4631909#4631909

Comment: Also this for handling async loops: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250746/process-chain-of-functions-without-ui-block/13252018#13252018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call `showResults()` after you've received the new data and pushed it to the array within the ajax callback.

```
var resultsArr = new Array();

// getResults()
// JSON response function -> takes uuid returned from search query
// and pings reponse url for any/all JSON objects of returned data
function getResults(req_uuid) {
    console.log("url fetched");
    $.getJSON( $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/respond?id=" + req_uuid, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        resultsArr.push(data);
        showResults(resultsArr);// <--- here
    });
}
```

Comment: but that will redisplay each previous element since `showResults` is stepping through `resultsArr` with a for loop

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I don't see a loop inside of the `showResults()` function. I could be possibly missing something. Can you post more code if there is a loop involved?

Comment: you're right I didn't post it. I just pasted up to the relevant section for the sake of brevity. Thanks for the help, though.